# Gray line at top of custom UITableViewCell on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with different types of cells. Some of the cells are standard `UITableViewCell's` and some are custom cells. On iPhone's everything works fine. But on iPad's I get a gray line above any `UILabel` within my custom cells. Standard cells display just fine. I create the custom cells with `initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1`, create the subviews within that method and position them during `layoutSubviews`.

It is as though a top border is being displayed for any UILabel I add to my custom cells and it only happens on the iPad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much experimenting I finally discovered the cause of the problem. I had another table view in my app with one custom cell and several standard cells. In that table view, the custom cell did not have the gray line. As it turned out, when I was calculating the position and size of my subviews during `layoutSubviews`, the cell that did not exhibit the problem had all whole numbers for the origin and size. Whereas, the cells with the problem had fractions. When I modified the code to ensure that all x's, y's, width's and height's had whole numbers, the gray lines disappeared.